# What is the meaning of the message Piscata Rosea 4 4 5

Tags: lands-of-lore-the-throne-of-chaos

In Lands of Lore - The Throne of Chaos, when you're in the Mines of Urbish, at level 3, you find a note saying PISCATA ROSEA 4 4 5

[image: Piscata Rosea 4 4 5]

My latin is prety old, but I'm sure Piscata means fish and Rosea means pink, but I don't understand the meaning of it. I'm pretty sure this is not a side-quest (the game doesn't have side-quests), and The Cutting Room Floor doesn't list that as an element from unused content.

Moreover, the comprehension of this is not needed to beat the game, so I really don't understand what it means and why it's here.

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [Easter egg and a red herring](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222203/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-message-piscata-rosea-4-4-5). It's a reference to a fish you can find in a previous game made by the same developers called Kyrandia. It was named "Piscata Rosea" and served no purpose in the game except to mislead you into thinking it might have one. Just like the note you found.

Comment: Oh, Thann you! Si I assume that "4 4 5" serves nu purpose either?

Comment: @Tloz Not that I can find. The numbers are probably there just to make it look more important.

Comment: Twenty years of my life, spent on a pointless mystery... Feel sad, but thank you anyway